# Hide and display element onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery.
I have two `p` tag with class of `.angle_up` and `.angle_down`.

`angle_up` class have `active` class. While clicking on `.angle_down` remove the `.active` class from `angle_up` and set to `.angle_down`.

Have to display the `ele` with animated effect while class has `active`. Like toggle.
How to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```js
 $(document).on("click", ".angle_up", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        var angledwn = $('.angle_down');
        angledwn.addClass("active");
        var ele = $('.ele');
        ele.toggle('5000');
    });
```

```css
.angle_up, .angle_down{
    color: #0096C9;
    display: none;
}
.angle_up.active, .angle_down.active{
    color: #0096C9;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="angle up active">First</p>

<p class="angle_down"> Second</p>



<p class="ele">To hide to display</p>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for that. Simply my question is explained on below kittycat's answer. And i've commented the little change over there

Comment: For example check first demo on this [link](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typing mistake in your html. Class is `angle_up` instead of `angle.up`.

Add an extra common class `.angle` to your both `.angle_up` and `.angle_down` and use that class as selector for your click event.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".angle", function () {
        var angledwn = $('.angle').not('.active');
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        angledwn.addClass("active");
        var ele = $('.ele');
        ele.toggle('5000');
    });
```

```css
.angle_up, .angle_down{
    color: #0096C9;
    display: none;
}
.angle_up.active, .angle_down.active{
    color: #0096C9;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="angle angle_up active">First</p>
<p class="angle angle_down"> Second</p>
<p class="ele">To hide to display</p>
```

Comment: Little change. How to display the hided text on click of text "second"

Answer (score 1):

You need not to select element by class  to achieve this just select by tag p and use .not() to add class on the P element which was not clicked.

```js
$(document).on("click", "p", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $("p").not(this).addClass("active");
        var ele = $('.ele');
        ele.toggle('5000');
    });
```

```css
.angle_up, .angle_down{
    color: #0096C9;
    display: none;
}
.angle_up.active, .angle_down.active{
    color: #0096C9;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="angle_up active">First</p>

<p class="angle_down"> Second</p>



<p class="ele">To hide to display</p>
```

P.S : `<p class="angle up active">First</p>`

you need to correct it, it should be

```
 <p class="angle_up active">First</p>
```

you are missing _ in class name

Comment: Thank you and +1 for gud answer